# Close Colobox iframe - submit parent form?

Tags: jquery, parent-child, colorbox, form-submit

I have a Colorbox on my form. The Colorbox click launches an iFrame where I have embedded code for them to upload stuff.

When they close the Colorbox , I want the parent form to "submit" so that when they come back on the screen they see the changes they made on the parent form.

Thanks to StackOverflow, I found how to do a reload of the parent window no problem. Problem is if they user typed anything prior to colorbox click, it is gone.

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%",**onClosed:function(){ location.reload(true);** }});
```

I'm looking for is some piece of code that fires off the parent form submit when the ColorBox is closed.

Ive tried lots of things - no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%",onClosed:function(){ $('form').submit(); }});
```

This should be pretty straight forward.  If it's not working then I would say you'll have to show more of your work for others to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: Perfect - so simple!  Jack rocks!  Thank you!